# How to add new line in Markdown presentation?

Tags: markdown, r-markdown, presentation

How to add new line in Markdown presentation?

I mean, something like `\newline` in TeX.

Answer (score 487, accepted):

See [the original markdown specification](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p) (bold mine):

> The implication of the “one or more consecutive lines of text” rule is that Markdown supports “hard-wrapped” text paragraphs. This differs significantly from most other text-to-HTML formatters (including Movable Type’s “Convert Line Breaks” option) which translate every line break character in a paragraph into a `<br />` tag.
>
> **When you do want to insert a `<br />` break tag using Markdown, you end a line with two or more spaces, then type return.**

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesnt work with headers... I would like to add break line (or just set bigger space) between the header and the rest of the slide.

Comment: @Mariusz, I don't know what presentation tool you are using, but assuming it's HTML-based I urge you to adjust the spacing with CSS. Markdown isn't concerned with design at all; it's all about content, and adding a blank line for spacing isn't a good semantic fit.

Comment: What if I want a break line inside a table cell. I don't think this would work.

Comment: @EduardoReis, tables aren't part of [the original Markdown specification](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) nor the widely-used [Commonmark specification](https://spec.commonmark.org/current/). Implementations that support them all have different rules and there are at least three widely-used table syntaxes. You can try using `<br>` in a table, but the result will depend entirely on the specific tool that you're using.

Comment: @Chris, thanks for the clarification. I am using Pandoc. It confuses me that pandoc "works" with `<br>` if I am converting it to HTML. I guess it just keeps the `<br>` there and the browser does the job, sort of. But with the PDF format, it doesn't work. I tried other option, but none worked with pandoc, I might be missing a flag or something.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it does. You might be able to get it working in your PDF with ``\\``, but that won't work in HTML :-). There's probably already a question about line breaks in tables from Markdown using Pandoc, but if you can't find one feel free to ask a new one.

Comment: This reminds me of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language) .

Answer (score 597):

Just add `\` at the end of line. For example

```
one\
two
```

Will become

```
one
two
```

It's also better than two spaces because it's visible.

Edit:
It doesn't work in some markdown applications, so it may cause incompatibility.
https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#line-break-best-practices

Comment: I prefer this solution over the others because I have my IDE set to automatically trim extra whitespace at the end of a line. I don't want to turn that setting off just for this purpose, since it helps keep my code clean.

Comment: Jep, trailing whitespace as semantic meaning is just the biggest antipattern in code or docs :)

Comment: This doesn't actually work in markdown, sigh. I've seen it work in some renderers, but I don't know offhand which.

What I do is write <space>\<space>. The \ quotes the second space and serves as a visual cue that I *intend* for there to be two spaces at the end.

The problem is, there may not actually BE a space after the \, in which case it fails. But better than two invisible spaces. So often I go with <br />.

I agree with @mark—biggest antipattern ever. Right up there with semantic tabs in old makefiles.

Comment: Great!. It is in the [CommonMark Specs](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#hard-line-breaks)

Comment: By the way, this is not recommended. https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#line-break-best-practices

Comment: @Pavel_K But most Linters don't like  inline html.

So its either:
- Trailing whitespaces (*nobody* likes them, i hope...)
- Ignoring Recomendations
- Ignoring Linters

Comment: This is a good solution and it works in nearly all places. But as of June 2022, it doesn't work on the Bitbucket website, when it displays markdown files or "Issues" bug reports (which are also markdown files). Bitbucket files must use the 'two empty spaces at end of line' method instead.

Comment: @Pavel_K, "not recommended" according to who? Is anybody authoritative behind that website? CommonMark is the closest thing we have to a universal Markdown spec and, as Madacol notes above, CommonMark includes this behaviour. Sure, there are tools that behave differently, but they're all so different from each other that you might as well restrict yourself to what's in the [original implementation](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) at that point. Unfortunately, the original version is not fully specified.

Comment: It works in PyCharm preview for Markdown files.

Answer (score 166):

> How to add new line in Markdown presentation?

Check the following resource [`Line Return`](http://markdown-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basics.html#line-return)

> **To force a line return, place two empty spaces at the end of a line.**

Comment: The issue with this is that I clear trailing whitespace from all files, which  would break markdown files using this method.

Comment: Then setup the trailing-space removal code to ignore markdown files. That's the language syntax, removing trailing-spaces in Markdown context is like removing semi-colons in PHP files. Or you can use @racoon_lord's solution.

Answer (score 85):

MarkDown file in three way to Break a Line

> **`<br />`** Tag Using

```
paragraph First Line <br /> Second Line
```

> **`\`** Using

```
First Line sentence \
Second Line sentence
```

> **`space keypress two times`** Using

```
First Line sentence␠␠
Second Line sentence
```

Paragraphs in use **`<br />`** tag.

Multiple sentences in using **`\`** or two times press **`space key`** then `Enter` and write a new sentence.

Comment: This should be marked as the updated correct solution as `<br />` is the only solution here that worked in the Markdown implemented within StackExchange's UI.

Comment: This is my personal favorite explanation. You have all of them listed and show clearly and simply.

Answer (score 80):

You could use `&nbsp;` in R markdown to create a new blank line.

For example, in your .Rmd file:

```
I want 3 new lines: 

&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;

End of file.
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think it's wrong? @user3441843

Comment: I think it's correct. The other answers are wrong (including the accepted answer)

Comment: if you are using marked as the mardown render you should add  breaks:true as option https://github.com/markedjs/marked/issues/835

Comment: @user3441843, what's wrong with the accepted answer?

Comment: Why does `&nbsp;` create a newline in R Markdown when it is the HTML code for inserting a [non-breaking space](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye its not that `&nbsp;` is creating the _new line_ but it's fooling the parser that would normally truncate consecutive blank lines, so this is putting a whitespace character on each line, so the line is no longer zero length.

Comment: This works for me, when none of the other solutions have. It only seems able to insert 1 blank line though no matter how many times I copy and paste `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 31):

What worked for me

```
\
&nbsp;
\
&nbsp;
```

[image]

Comment: i just used &nbsp;  didnt need the \

Answer (score 26):

Just add a `\` in a new line and it will be fine.

```
\
```

Comment: This has already been mentioned in some of the other answers.

Comment: This was the answer that I needed.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on what kind of markdown parser you're using. For example in [showdownjs](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown/wiki/Showdown-Options) there is an option `{simpleLineBreaks: true}` which gives corresponding html for the following md input:

```
a line
wrapped in two
```

```html
<p>a line<br>
wrapped in two</p>
```

Answer (score 7):

If none of the solutions mentions here work for you, which is what happened with me, then you can do the following:
**Add an empty header (A hack that ruins semantics)**

```
text
####
text
```

Just make sure that when the header is added it has no border in bottom of it in the markdown css, so you can try different variations of the headers.

Answer (score 4):

I was using [Markwon](https://github.com/noties/Markwon) for markdown parsing in Android. The following worked great:

```
"My first line  \nMy second line  \nMy third line  \nMy last line"
```

...two spaces followed by `\n` at the end of each line.

Comment: Wonderful solution for adding multiple lines of descriptions in NFT metadata. To be noted that `<br />` would cause the description to disappear on platforms like Opensea.

Answer (score 4):

> Neither a double space or \ at the end of a paragraph worked for me, however having a blank line between text in the code did, as did adding `<p>` at the start of the paragraph (having `</p>` at the end wasn't necessary)

```
    first paragraph

    second paragraph
```

```
    <p> first paragraph
    <p> second paragraph
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other responses two spaces and enter will create a carriage return in markdown. The problem is your editor may trim that trailing whitespace. OP didn't mention a specific editor. In the case of VS Code you can suppress trimming on a per syntax basis in the settings.json file:

```
  "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
  "[markdown]": {
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": false
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also wrap it in a fenced code block. The advantage of this approach is you need not go for additional stuff for every line.
However, the content shall be displayed as a highlighted block with a background, so it may not be apt for all use cases.

```
Lorem inmissa qui propinquas doleas
Accipe fuerat accipiam
```

Answer (score -6):

The newline character (\n) can be used to add a newline into a markdown file programmatically. For example, it is possible to do like this in python:

```
with open("file_name.md", "w") as file:
   file.write("Some text")
   file.write("\n")
   file.write("Some other text")
```

Comment: This is a good answer since it gives the hint that \n\r does not work (esp. in C# UWP Markdown component). Only \n does the job.