# Increase the space between two plots in RMD

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I have been trying to create a report in RMD, but the plots are appearing right after each other. I would like to add more spaces in-between each plots. I would really appreciate if you can assist me on this.

```
ggplot(data = drivers.clean, aes(x = Age)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = as.factor(Smoker))) 

ggplot(data = drivers.clean, aes(x = Age)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Sex))
```

Here is how my results are appearing in the PDF:
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33191744/how-to-add-new-line-in-markdown-presentation

Comment: That method only works on HTML not for PDF.

Comment: can't you just use standard LaTex, i.e. `\linebreak`?

Comment: Can I put that in r{ }?

Comment: only one way to find out...it'll work, or it won't

Comment: or use two different R chunks separated by however many linebreaks provides a good aesthetic

Comment: For HTML: `<br/>` after the code chunk with the first plot.
For PDF: `\vspace{10em}` after the code chunk with the first block

Comment: I want to keep them all in the same code chunk. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I think you can  use cat("\\linebreak") in the chunk

Comment: @RichardTelford, I am now getting the ## in the output. I even setup the echo = FALSE and messages = FALSE

Comment: you might need chunk option `results = 'asis'`. My code works with `cat("\n\n\\pagebreak\n\n")`