# Line Breaks with \newline not working when knitting Word documents with latest updates?

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown

I recently updated RStudio to version 1.2.1335 and my *rmarkdown* package to version 1.12. All other packages have been updated.

Before updating, I was able to knit line breaks in Word documents by inserting `\newline` in R Markdown code, but it's no longer working.

I am still able to insert page breaks with a word template and heading styles as shown [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-markdown-how-to-insert-page-breaks-in-a-ms-word-document/).

Here's an example of my YAML header (hasn't changed since updating):

```
---
title: "Document Title"
date:  Created `r strftime(Sys.time(),format="%B-%d-%Y at %H:%M")`
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: template.docx
---
```

Anybody else having this issue or have any ideas on how to fix this? Issue shows up on both on Windows 10 and macOS Mojave.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same experience with rmarkdown version 1.18 on macOS Mojave.  [racoon_lord's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58465541/10576221) works for me, which is to insert a `\` at the end of the line to create a new line in MS Word document.  (I have not tried this with an example that uses a template file.)