# Are newline tags in HTML equivalent to newline formatting in Markdown?

Tags: html, markdown

I know **HTML** treats newlines as `br`. Even when **markdown** is converted to **html**, is newline processing treated as a `br` tag?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add new line in Markdown presentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33191744/how-to-add-new-line-in-markdown-presentation)

Comment: Sorry but no... I would like to know which tags are converted when converting line breaks to 'HTML' in 'Markdown'.

Comment: There's no one "markdown". The original spec was ambiguous in some places and so a few incompatible parsers were created. There's a push for standardization in form of [Commonmark](https://commonmark.org/). You can look at that spec. Otherwise, just experiment with the parser you use.

Answer (score 0):

[In general](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p), single line breaks don't do anything:

> A paragraph is simply one or more consecutive lines of text, separated by one or more blank lines. (A blank line is any line that looks like a blank line — a line containing nothing but spaces or tabs is considered blank.) Normal paragraphs should not be indented with spaces or tabs.

In other words, these are equivalent:

```
One long paragraph.
```

```
One
long
paragraph.
```

If you wish to generate a `<br>` tag you may end a line with two or more spaces:

```
One paragraph␠␠
containing a `<br>`.
```

A blank line separates paragraphs:

```
One paragraph.

Another paragraph.
```

As Sergio says in a comment, Markdown is somewhat fragmented. But these rules are used pretty consistently across dialects.

Comment: I understand! Thx Chris!!