# GitHub .md keyboard shorcut for <br/>

Tags: github, syntax, newline, shortcut, readme

When editing a `README.md` on GitHub, is there a **keyboard shortcut for `<br/>` in GitHub**?

*(Especially, when writing the tables, I type a lot of `<br/>` tags)*

Regards,
Saeid

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33191744/how-to-add-new-line-in-markdown-presentation), you can simply hit `Space` twice and then hit `Enter`.

Inserting `\` also works, so

```
One,\
two\
three
```

will result as

```
One,
two
three
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

I'm not sure if it works when editing a table.
Because, using '\' or 'Space' + 'Enter' will change the column and start a new line from the first left column.

I'm exactly looking for a keyboard shortcut or tips to type '<br>' quicker.