# NFT Metadata: Have more than one line of description

Tags: metadata, nft

is it possible to have more than one line of words as the description of the metadata json of an NFT? I have browsed several examples on the Internet and all of them are using just one line, like this one from NFTSchool:

```json
{
    "title": "Asset Metadata",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Identifies the asset to which this NFT represents"
        },
        "description": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Describes the asset to which this NFT represents"
        },
        "image": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "A URI pointing to a resource with mime type image/* representing the asset to which this NFT represents. Consider making any images at a width between 320 and 1080 pixels and aspect ratio between 1.91:1 and 4:5 inclusive."
        }
    }
}
```

This example's description:

```
Describes the asset to which this NFT represents
```

Is it possible to have something like this that can change lines on marketplaces like Opensea and Rarible? (The following example is supposed to have three lines of description)

```json
{
    "title": "Asset Metadata",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Identifies the asset to which this NFT represents"
        },
        "description": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Describes the asset to which this NFT represents\nDescribes the asset to which this NFT represents\nDescribes the asset to which this NFT represents"
        },
        "image": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "A URI pointing to a resource with mime type image/* representing the asset to which this NFT represents. Consider making any images at a width between 320 and 1080 pixels and aspect ratio between 1.91:1 and 4:5 inclusive."
        }
    }
}
```

This example's desired description:

```
Describes the asset to which this NFT represents
Describes the asset to which this NFT represents
Describes the asset to which this NFT represents
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\n` works for letting those descriptions change line on Opensea. Haven't tested on other platforms yet but it should work everywhere.

Example:

```json
{
    description: "Line one  \nLine two  \nLine three"
}
```

What it will show:

```
Line one
Line two
Line three
```

It will automatically ignore the extra spaces before and after   `\n`.

Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60083782/11421839