# FastAPI - generated doc page doesn't show endpoint

Tags: python, fastapi, docstring

I try to create a simple FastAPI app:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class RephrasingRequest(BaseModel):
    content: str
    """The content to rephrase"""

    n_outputs: int = 1
    """How many examples to generate?"""




app_debug = FastAPI(
    title="debug", description="View project's README.md for details", docs_url="/"
)


@app_debug.post("/rephrase")
async def rephrase_question(request: RephrasingRequest) -> str:
    msg = "got the request " + str(request)
    return msg
```

When I go to the app SwaggerUI page, I see the endpoint documentation, but it says "No parameters", as if the function does not accept parameters.

[screenshot of the original doc page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8U1eF.png)

Also, and I think this is related, the UI doesn't format the documentation properly. For example, if I add the following docstring:

```
@app_debug.post("/rephrase")
async def rephrase_question(request: RephrasingRequest) -> str:
    """
    This is a sample doc.

    :param request:
        The request

    :return:
        What we return
    """

    msg = "got the request " + str(request)
    return msg
```

the result is malformatted
[screenshot of the modififed doc page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoOk5.png)

(note that the formatting strings are there)

I expected to see propely formatted documentation, including a proper list of parameters

Comment: The function does not accept parameters (which would be `?foo=123`). It _does show_ the expected _request body_, which matches what you've defined. The comment format is Markdown, and markdown does not consider a new line as anything other than plain text (i.e. not a break) if you've just indented the next line. You can test it in the editor here on SO. If you want to have a newline, you can usually do that by using the expected Mardown format: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33191744/how-to-add-new-line-in-markdown-presentation (end the line with two spaces)

Comment: > the function does not accept parameters



But it does (`request`), unless FastAPI calls this something else?

Comment: You're confusing _arguments to your HTTP endpoint_ and _arguments to the function_. You have a Pydantic model as the argument, this is mapped as a _request body_ to HTTP endpoint (which you can see in your screenshot below the part about parameters). When you're talking about parameters _to the endpoint_, those would be what you find in a query string (`?foo=bar`). The model you've told your function to expect has to be mapped to a JSON _body_, and not URL parameters (since it can be a complex model). If you want query parameters, use `def foo(bar: int)` directly or `bar: int = Query(...)`.

Comment: @MatsLindh, thank you very much. If you could write your comments as an answer, I will be able to mark it "accepted"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing arguments *to your HTTP endpoint* and *arguments to your python  function*.

You have a Pydantic model as the argument, this is mapped as a *request body* to HTTP endpoint (which you can see in your screenshot below the part about parameters).

When you're talking about parameters to the endpoint, those [would be what you find in a query string](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/) (`?foo=bar`). The model you've told your function to expect has to be mapped to a JSON body, and not URL parameters (since it can be a complex model).

If you want query parameters, use:

```py
def foo(bar: int):
# or
def foo(bar: int = Query(...)):
```

The comment format is Markdown, and markdown does not consider a new line as anything other than plain text (i.e. not a break) if you've just indented the next line. If you want to have a newline, you can usually [do that by using the expected Markdown format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33191744/how-to-add-new-line-in-markdown-presentation) (end the line with two spaces)